# ASP.NET 5 MVC Application and Wordpress on IIS Virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, web-hosting, plesk

We have a WordPress application (PHP) hosted on [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) (simplified URL) and another web application (C# with ASP.NET 4.8. framework) for another workflow.

Second web application (C#) needs to be deployed on [www.website.com/appName](http://www.website.com/appName).

We created VirtualDirectory "appName" and published application into that directory, but on [www.website.com/appName](http://www.website.com/appName) we get 404 response with error.php view (404 page for [www.website.com](http://www.website.com), not for second app [www.website.com/appName](http://www.website.com/appName))

"Authorization" redirect for C# app works because when we request [www.website.com/appName](http://www.website.com/appName), URL changes to [www.website.com/appName/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FappName%2F](http://www.website.com/appName/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FappName%2F), meaning that the C# application registers its redirect rules.
My guess is that application found "Home" controller and redirected to "Login" controller because of [Authorize] tag (which is desired behavior), but I don`t know why application returns 404 with error.php instead of /login/index.

We tested the application on [www.appName.website.com](http://www.appName.website.com) and it works perfectly but that is not what we need.

Main problem is that server is on hosting and we don`t have full access to server (only via Plesk CP so IIS config is limited).

So basically, my question comes down to: how to publish a C# .NET MVC application under WordPress Plesk hosted page?

Comment: Does your wordpress site run under IIS?

Comment: Yes, it runs on IIS, but we can only access it via Plesk hosting control panel.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I have the same issue and not able to resolve. I have access to my own server though.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we have changed the complete way we published it. We run a second server in the end.